# Create a form in excel and output to a predefined pdf format

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vbscript

Problem:
We are a [travel agency](http://www.zopky.com) and we deal with making lots of itineraries everyday which is a long and tedious task. Now we want to make a form in excel (other suggestions welcome) where we can put in details of the itinerary like flights, hotel and activities and output it to a pdf which is well designed with all the data inputs from the excel sheet.

Possible Solution:
I think it is possible to do it with VB, but i'd appreciate if someone can redirect me to an example which I can use
But what I really want it, can we directly edit the pdf?

Maybe, we can even put it up on our [blog](http://blog.zopky.com) and let users edit the pdf directly?

I know this might be little vague or amateur-ish so please bear with me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. We are not here to take you from start to finish, nor suggest what application to use. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches. For example, use one sheet of your Excel file to arrange the itinerary data in a styled environment (yes, using VBA will help with that). Then save the Excel file as a PDF, which will result in just the active (styled) sheet to appear in the PDF.

The very purpose of a PDF is that it can NOT be easily edited. That's why itineraries are sent out as PDFs, so that people don't accidentally change their flight dates around and then blame you when they miss their flight. I'm not sure I understand the significance of having a user's itinerary with their travel details as an editable PDF on your blog. That's very personal information, no?

I assume you really mean something completely different. So, please edit your post and describe what you really want to do. I can then edit this answer to address that need.